# doopl bin directory path

Tags: python-3.x, docplex, doopl

I added the bin directory path of opl on system environment setting.

Following is the path.

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\opl\bin\x64_win64
```

However, the doopl keeps giving me error like below

```
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\doopl\opl.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise ImportError('Could not import OPL wrappers. Make sure than OPL bin directory is in the PATH')
ImportError: Could not import OPL wrappers. Make sure than OPL bin directory is in the PATH
```

Is there any other path I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I recently updated my CPLEX version and had the same error. Once I updated doopl, it solved the problem:
pip install doopl --upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to upgrade doopl as mentionned by Joshua ? If you have an older version of doopl, it will not find the COS 12.10 libraries.